# Installing Composer PHP Where is the Vendor/Autoload.php?

Tags: php

I have done installing composer.

Here is the git
https://github.com/seregazhuk/php-pinterest-bot

I did

```
php /home/admin/ocicio/botsector/php-pinterest-bot-master/composer.json install
```

The response

```
{
    "name": "seregazhuk/pinterest-bot",
    "description": "PHP library for Pintrest",
    "keywords": [
        "php",
        "lib",
        "pinterest"
    ],
    "type": "package",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "src/Helpers/functions.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "seregazhuk\\PinterestBot\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "seregazhuk\\PinterestBot\\": "src",
            "seregazhuk\\tests\\": "tests"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-fileinfo": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "codeclimate/php-test-reporter": "^0.4.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Sergey Zhuk",
            "email": "seregazhuk88@gmail.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, as the return, I do not receive the autoload.php.

Can anyone enlighten me where is the file located? Thank you.

Comment: What directory are you currently in when executing that command?

Comment: I don't think that's how you'd install the package...Typically you'll want to be in the directory where your composer.json file lives and run ```composer require seregazhuk/pinterest-bot```

Comment: Where did you get the idea to run `php` on that package's `composer.json` file? PHP only processes stuff in `<?php` PHP tags `?>`; it passes everything else through untouched. That's what's happening here: the entire `composer.json` is simply being echoed back.

Comment: @Phil I am on /home/admin/ocicio/botsector/

Comment: @BrianPutt I tried the code but receive "-bash: composer: command not found"

Comment: @Chris I get it from https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies

Comment: @Bobby, that documentation says to run `php composer.phar install`. And if you're adding a library to your project (instead of working with a codebase that already depends on it) you should use the `composer require` command that Brian gave above. In both cases you're running _Composer_, not `php`, on the JSON file. There is no situation where running `php` directly on a `composer.json` file will be helpful (unless it's a very strange JSON file).

Comment: Looking at this again, I think you're confusing the `composer.json` file with the Composer binary (which might be called `composer.phar` or just `composer`, depending how you installed Composer). The former is a data file and the latter is a program. Since you've seen "composer: command not found" from your shell, do you have a `composer.phar` somewhere?

Comment: @Chris It works now, I forgot to make it Globally. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps, but I'm glad you got this working.